# How to build an If condition about last page

Tags: java, xml, apache, xslt, apache-fop

I need to find a solution to this problem: I have to build an If condition that says "If this is the last page I'll show you this row, otherwise I won't".

Down below I'm going to show you the code so that you can better understand what I'm trying to say.

I've already tried building a variable with "therverylastpage" but it seems a stupid solution.

```
<xsl:if test="how can I do this?">
    <fo:table-row>
        <fo:table-cell  padding="0.1cm">

            <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%" border="1pt solid black" margin-top="0.2cm" >
                <fo:table-column column-width="15%"/>
                <fo:table-column column-width="15%"/>
                <fo:table-column column-width="10%"/>
                <fo:table-column column-width="10%"/>
                <fo:table-column column-width="50%"/>
                <fo:table-header >
                    <fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-cell padding="0.1cm">
                            <fo:block text-align="right" font-size="9">Importo</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell padding="0.1cm">
                            <fo:block text-align="right"  font-size="9">Iva</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell padding="0.1cm">
                            <fo:block text-align="right" font-size="9">Aliquota</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell padding="0.1cm">
                            <fo:block text-align="center" font-size="9">C.iva</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell padding="0.1cm">
                            <fo:block font-size="9">Descrizione</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                </fo:table-header>
                <fo:table-body>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="piede/iva/ivariga"/>
                </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>
            <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%" margin-top="0.5cm" border="1pt solid black">
                <fo:table-body >
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="piede/totdoc"/>
                </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>
            <fo:block margin-top="0.5cm" text-align="center" font-size="10">
                <xsl:value-of select="notepagamento"/>
            </fo:block>
            <fo:block id="TheVeryLastPage"> </fo:block>

        </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: When the XSLT is being applied to your input XML (which you did not include in the question, so we don't know what it looks like) there is no concept of "page": you are just processing an XML file and creating another file (in this case, an XLS-FO file). Then, when the FO file is given to a formatter (FOP, in this case) there are no `xsl:if` inside it (or it won't be a valid FO file). So, you either have to find an appropriate XSLT boolean expression referring to your input file and put in the XSLT, or create the FO elements and attributes so that FOP will produce what you want.

Comment: What are the difficulties you are finding putting your content in the last page? I suspect your description is missing some important points, as the _last row_ of a table will naturally appear on the _last page_ of the output if there is no other content after it.

Comment: @lfurini I want to show the table only in the last page, in a position that I decide. Do I must use the method of layou master set or there is a  " IF " solution?